# hide vimeo share buttons in free account

Tags: icons, hide, share, vimeo

I have vimeo free account. I am showing the videos in iframe. Can I hide the share icons coming on it?

Is it possible to hide? Or an other way around if want to have my own share icons. OR using vimeo api is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo Basic (free) members cannot hide the share icons in their embedded player instances. Only paid (Plus/PRO/Business) members can customize their video embeds to this extent. See the Help Center article here:

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224969968-Embedding-videos-overview

Comment: yes... that's right.... thats why  I specified in question if free account people can do anything..

Comment: And the answer is "No". Sorry that it's not the answer you were hoping to receive, but that's it.